# How to remove redis specific application cache via capistrano prior to a restart

Tags: redis, capistrano

How to remove redis specific application cache via capistrano prior to a restart. Redis is running a remote machine and the redis client need not be installed on the machine which performs the deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as capistrano can run any command upon deployment, just remove the cache key(s) with redis-cli:

```
role :redisserver, "127.0.0.1"
...

namespace :deploy do
...

before "deploy:restart", "deploy:reset_redis_cache"
task :reset_redis_cache, :roles => :rediserver do
  run "redis-cli DEL cachekey"
end

...
```

UPD. added role reference

Comment: Thanks @maxivano, but as I mentioned earlier the machine mostly will not have the redis-cli client installed

Comment: @Rpj You said machine _which_ performs the deployment. So the one you deploy _to_ doesn't have redis cli too?

Comment: The machine to which it will be deployed, should have a redis-server and a redis-cli. So I am assuming the above command runs in the deployed to machine and hence would run without any issues.

Comment: @Rpj updated answer with remote server reference (in case redis server is on another machine). Please accept answer if you tried it and it worked.